# How to remove +27 when you enter cellphone number and replace with 0

Tags: php, html

How to remove +27 and replace it with (060), I have a text field where I want to enter +27608797221 and format to (060) 879-7221 ,my problem is it only works when I enter 0608797221 without +27. I want this to work in both side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Phone Number Format</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter phone number">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phone'];
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phoneNumber);
    $formatNumber = "(" . substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3) . ") " . substr($phoneNumber, 3, 3) . 
     "-" . substr($phoneNumber, 6);
     echo "phone number: " . $formatNumber;
  }
 ?>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number starts with `'27'` after the non-digit characters have been removed, and if so, replace `'27'` with `'0'`.

```
if(isset($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phone']; // +27xxxx
    $phoneNumber = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $phoneNumber); // 27xxxx

    // If number starts with '27', replace it with '0'
    if (substr($phoneNumber, 0, 2) == '27') {
        $phoneNumber = '0' . substr($phoneNumber, 2); // 0xxxx
    }

    $formatNumber = "(" . substr($phoneNumber, 0, 3) . ") " . substr($phoneNumber, 3, 3) . "-" . substr($phoneNumber, 6);
    echo "phone number: " . $formatNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort it really works they way I wanted it.

Comment: @Nick if works, accept + vote will help my reputation

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, you could also use the PHP 8 function str_starts_with(): https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php

Comment: @Wimanicesir does the same thing right? `if (str_starts_with($phoneNumber, '27')) {`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, yeah that's what I said.. *You could also* means it works now but it could also work with that. Just providing additional information.

Comment: @Wimanicesir good to know anyway. Thanks <3

Comment: The main difference between `str_starts_with` (or `strpos() === 0`) and `substr() === 'xxx'` is that `substr` creates a new string when `str_starts_with` (or `strpos`) doesn't.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte appreciate for the the explanation.